# Hi, I had created Elixir project with phoenix framework. there is yaml file when i build that file i get this error

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto, elixir-mix

```
== Compilation error in file lib/ecto/query.ex ==
** (Kernel.TypespecError) lib/ecto/query.ex:428: type dynamic/0 is a built-in type and it cannot be redefined
    (elixir 1.15.0) lib/kernel/typespec.ex:961: Kernel.Typespec.compile_error/2
    (stdlib 5.0.1) lists.erl:1599: :lists.foldl_1/3
    (elixir 1.15.0) lib/kernel/typespec.ex:226: Kernel.Typespec.translate_typespecs_for_module/2
could not compile dependency :ecto, "mix compile" failed. Errors may have been logged above. You can recompile this dependency with "mix deps.compile ecto --force", update it with "mix deps.update ecto" or clean it with "mix deps.clean ecto"
ERROR: Service 'cense_live_chat' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c mix do compile' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

for building yam file I have up my Postgres service too. I have tried using the command shown in error `mix deps.compile ecto --force`, update it with `mix deps.update ecto` or clean it with `mix deps.clean ecto`.
so anyone knows what to do about the above error????

Comment: Please provide that file as well, looks like you are trying to define a type `dynamic` as custom type, but you can't use it.

Comment: Do you mean that lib/ecto/query.ex file?

Comment: yes, please point me to the repository if you can or give me some more insights, give file where you made changes etc, because I'm assuming that new project didn't give any issue & you updated something which resulted in this error, I need to see that change.

Comment: also please let me know your OTP version, this error came in latest OTP version 26 as they introduced new `dynamic` type.

Comment: I would recommend to use the following versions for quick fix, otherwise you might need to make some changes in the ecto dependency.


```elixir

erlang 25.1.2

elixir 1.14.2-otp-25


```

Comment: or you could use the  {:ecto, "~> 3.10"} version. please feel free to use any, let me know if it works.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 6):

Update the ecto version to `{:ecto, "~> 3.10"}` version as the latest OTP and ecto was having the type `dynamic` in common. so ecto updated the name to `dynamic_expr` so to fix this issue.
either upgrade the ecto or downgrade the OTP.